# Livecode Browser widget not setting cookies?

Tags: browser, livecode

It appears from my research that the browser widget in Livecode does not record cookies, nor does there not seem to be other methods at play. Two pieces of evidence: in Livecode, when I return to a site that has previously alerted me to a cookie being set—having said yes the first time—it asks me again when I return to that site; item two: when I open Chrome’s cookie storage, I don’t see anything set after saying yes to a handful of sites. Could the browser widget be setting cookies elsewhere, like in a Windows folder? Or does the Livecode browser require some additional code to record cookies?
TIA,
NerdZero

Answer (score 1):

When the app/stack is closed (in the proper way) the browser widget is destroyed together with all cookies that were set. Therefore it makes sense that next time when you create a new, fresh browser instance, that you get those pesky cooky warnings again. There is no way around it, except for perhaps executing a piece of JavaScript that automatically accepts any cookie warnings. This may be a real hassle to set up.

I don't think it is possible to read set cookies and restore them later, as such behaviour wouldn't be secure.

Comment: Mark, thanks for the very helpful answer. Most appreciated.

Comment: @JOHNHART If an answer is helpful, don't forget to vote for it and, may you decide that it is the definite answer, to accept it as such. Thanks.